# Struts 2 call param with java

Tags: java, tags, hidden

I have this code:

```
<%
  String param = "This my value";
%>
<s:hidden name="hdd"  value='<%=param%>' />
```

I want to call param variables, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the param defined on JSP page? If it is, try the html tag " />, but not struts2 tag . The struts2 tag will fetch it's value from OGNL stack according to it's name.